# Could a web-scraper get around a good throttle protection?

Tags: security, http, web-scraping

Suppose that a data source sets a tight IP-based throttle.  Would a web scraper have any way to download the data if the throttle starts rejecting their requests as early as 1% of the data being downloaded?

The only technique I could think of a hacker using here would be some sort of proxy system.  But, it seems like the proxies (even if fast) would eventually all reach the throttle.

**Update:** Some people below have mentioned big proxy networks like Yahoo Pipes and Tor, but couldn't these IP ranges or known exit nodes be blacklisted as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A list of thousands or poxies can be compiled for [FREE](http://yaph.sourceforge.net/). IPv6 addresses can be rented for **pennies**.   Hell, an attacker could boot up an Amazon EC2 micro instance for 2-7 cents an hour.

And you want to stop people from scraping your site?  The internet doesn't work that way,  and hopefully it never will.

(I have seen IRC servers do a port scan on clients  to see if the following ports are open: 8080,3128,1080.  However there are proxy servers that use different ports and there are also legit reasons to run proxy server or to have these ports open, like if you are running Apache Tomcat.  You could bump it up a notch by using YAPH to see if a client is running a proxy server.  In effect you'd be using an attacker's too against them ;)

Answer (score 2):

Someone using [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) would be hopping IP addresses every few minutes. I used to run a website where this was a problem, and resorted to blocking the IP addresses of known Tor exit nodes whenever excessive scraping was detected. You can implement this if you can find a regularly updated list of Tor exit nodes, for example, https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes

Comment: That tor_blacklist.txt link has been replaced with an advertisement. This site https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes offers a direct link https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/ all TOR exit nodes updated every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a P2P crawling network to accomplish this task. There will be a lot of IPs availble and there will be no problem if one of them become throttled. Also, you may combine a lot of client instances using some proxy configuration as suggested in previous answers.

I think you can use [YaCy](http://yacy.net/), a P2P opensource crawling network.

Answer (score 1):

A scraper that wants the information will get the information.  Timeouts, changing agent names, proxies, and of course EC2/RackSpace or any other cloud services that have the ability to start and stop servers with new IP addresses for pennies.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of people using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=sources#FetchPage) to do such things, essentially using Yahoo as a proxy to pull the data.

Comment: Still, wouldn't the Yahoo IP eventually be throttled?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running your scraper on amazon ec2 instances. Every time you get throttled, startup a new instance (at new IP), and kill the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the time the attacker has for obtaining the data. If most of the data is static, it might be interesting for an attacker to run his scraper for, say, 50 days. If he is on a DSL line where he can request a "new" IP address twice a day, 1% limit would not harm him that much.

Of course, if you need the data more quickly (because it is outdated quickly), there are better ways (use EC2 instances, set up a BOINC project if there is public interest in the collected data, etc.).

Or have a Pyramid scheme a la "get 10 people to run my crawler and you get PORN, or get 100 people to crawl it and you get LOTS OF PORN", as it was quite common a few years ago with ad-filled websites. Because of the competition involved (who gets the most referrals) you might quickly get a lot of nodes running your crawler for very little money.